# Implementing a User Login, JDBC Transactions question

Tags: java, database, jdbc, transactions

I have a question regarding database transactions where I'm not sure if my understanding is correct. I want to implement a user login in a java application. As there might be multiple servers acting on the same database, and each user can only log in one of those servers, the database has to store a flag if a user is already logged in.

So assume following table structure:

```
ID | User | PWD | Server
```

where `Server` is the reference to the server where the user is logged in to, or `NULL` if he's not logged in.

When a user logs in, I have to first check if the server value is NULL, and if not, set it to the correspondig reference value. But what happens when in between these 2 statements the user logs in on another server? Can such a condition be detected by transactions? e.g. (pseudo)

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = 'usr' AND password = 'pwd'");
if (rs.next()) {
  rs.getInt("Server");
  if (rs.wasNull()) {
    // Not logged in
    conn.createStatement().execute("UPDATE users SET server = 123 WHERE user = 'usr' AND password = 'pwd'");
    conn.commit();
  }
} else {
  // Usr/Pwd wrong
}
conn.rollback();
```

What happens if the user logs in between the select and update statements on another server? does the commit fail as the table was altered by someone else during the transaction, or is it executed nontheless?

Should I better use an approach like

```
UPDATE users SET server = 123 WHERE user = 'usr' AND pwd = 'pwd' AND server IS NULL
```

and check if 0 rows were affected? If so I have to check if the user exists in a query.

Simmilar issues arise when registering a new user with INSERT. Shoud I use the transaction approach, or declare the user column as UNIQUE and catch SQL exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using transactions as you suggest with your pseudocode will solve this, but make sure to set you transaction isolation level to TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ.  See this [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) for details.

You also need to think abount:

- Never, never, never store plain text passwords in the database.  You need to use a one-way hash.  Also, make sure to pay attention to the hashing-algorithm and implementation.  Search for "HBGary" and "Anonymous" to read about what might happen if you don't.
- Think about what will happen if the user logs in to one server, and the client crashes before he has a chance to log out.

Comment: Thanks for the link. And of course I would not store plain text PWDs... For handling crashes: The server detects when the socket connection is closed and therefore can log out the user at that point.

Comment: great, just thought i'd mention it to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of updating the user's row, you can specify to lock that particular row so that no other jdbc connection can modify it.

Comment: how do you explicitly lock a row in JDBC?

Comment: ok, this does basically the same thing as TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ.  I think setting isolation level is cleaner, because then you don't need separate queries depending on whether your are going do do an update later on or not.  Just decide what level of isolation you are comfortable with.  The SQL standard is not freely available, but the PostgreSQL documentation states that: "Although FOR UPDATE appears in the SQL standard, the standard allows it only as an option of DECLARE CURSOR. PostgreSQL allows it in any SELECT query as well as in sub-SELECTs, but this is an extension."